# Draw polytope with Graphics

Tags: graphics, geometry

How can I draw a polytope with the Graphics function? The documentation simply says that you can do it, but does not explain how. The example given only plots vertices, not the edges of the polytope. Using:

```
Graphics[Octagon]
```

gives an error. I also tried the following from a different question:

```
Graphics[Octagon & /@ Vertices[Octagon]]
```

and that does not work either. I also tried the following:

```
Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, #}] & /@ Vertices[Octagon]]
```

and that does not work either. I also tried this:

```
Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, #}] & /@ EdgeList[Octagon]]
```

and that gives an error as well. I also tried this:

```
Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, #}] & /@ Faces[Octagon]]
```

and that does not work. It would be useful to have an answer that explains how this stuff works, because I just don't get it and the documentation does not explain enough that I can figure out the internal logic of these functions. The documentation page on Polytopes says it is a "tutorial", but there is no tutorial. It just lists the functions and then gives four short examples.

I almost got it to work with this:

```
Graphics[Line[Vertices[Octagon]]]
```

But it does not close up the last point.

Comment: `Graphics[{Red, RegularPolygon[8], White, Text[Style["STOP", 110]]}]`

Comment: Nothing in the documentation for the  [Polytopes Package](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Polytopes/guide/PolytopesPackage.html) says you can use it with `Graphics`.  But this seems to work `Graphics@Polygon@Vertices@Octagon`

Comment: you mean [this](http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2016-10-15-00-36-37.png)?

Comment: @yode - that is really odd.  If you look at the resulting `Graphics`, you see they are using 1070 vertices to make an octagon!!!

Comment: If what you want is the outline of a polytope: `Graphics[{Black, RegularPolygon[1, 8], White, RegularPolygon[0.95, 8]}]`

Comment: @bills That is not a usage of the Polytope package.

Comment: ...and as Jason said, that package does not include a facility for drawing polygons. You can insist all you want, but...

Comment: @J.M. The documentation page shows the usage of Graphics to draw the vertices of polytopes.

Comment: Well sure, you can do ``Needs["Polytopes`"]; Graphics[Polygon[Vertices[Octagon]]]`` (modifying [the example in the docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Polytopes/tutorial/Polytopes.html#1590)), but then `RegularPolygon[8]` is usable without needing to load a package. As you see, all it provides is the coordinates; you do the drawing yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way to do this, maybe not optimal, but it does work:

```
Graphics[Line[Append[Vertices[Octagon], First[Vertices[Octagon]]]]]
```

which produces:

[image]

Vertices produces a list of x-y coordinates and Line builds a list of line objects for each of the vertices in a chain. You have to append the coordinates of the first vertice to the end of the list so that the last vertice connects to the first one and closes the figure.

Note that Polygon does not solve the problem economically because it does not generate a figure of lines, it generates a *region*.

Comment: Try `Graphics[{FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Black], Polygon[Vertices[Octagon]]}]`, or `Graphics[Line[{##, #1} & @@ Vertices[Octagon]]]`.